# From local to AWS Lambda Node:js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a folder working into my local MAC OSX, the node.js is working properly.
Now I want to export to AWS Lambda and execute code from there.
I tried to pack the code and upload, but I found issues.

I did this:
moved to the dir locally
zip with `zip -r ../polly.zip *`
then upload with

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name FUNCTIONNAME —region eu-west-1 --zip-file fileb://~/aws/FUNCTIONNAME.zip
```

The function is on Lambda, I see dependencies, node_modules, but when I test I obtain error :

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:979:15)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:1"
  ]
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342817/how-to-solve-runtime-handlernotfound-error-in-aws-lambda?

Comment: I have read it, but I have nothing like fn.
I have these 2

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uuid = require('uuid');

And I see the 2 in node_modules in Lambda, too.

Comment: Is your index.js at the root of your zip file? Does it have a function called handler as entry point?